# When exactly does the Evernote monthly usage meter reset?

Tags: evernote

I now that Evernote claim that it is every 30 days, but what time of day does this happen?

Is there any way to know in exactly how many more minutes the meter will be reset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens every month on the same day at 12 AM. That means it won't be exactly every 30 days, since some months have 31 days, for example.

Each client's "days left in cycle" behaves differently. The Mac and iPhone clients will display the amount of days inclusively, while the PC and web clients display the amount of whole days left. For example, let's say that the time is 11 PM, on the last day (i.e. in 1 hour, the usage meter will reset), the Mac client will say "1 day left in cycle", while the PC client will say "0 days left in cycle". Similarly, on a month with 31 days, immediately after the meter is reset, the Mac client will say "31 days left in cycle", while the PC client will say "30 days left in cycle".

Answer (score 0):

You can check this on Evernote setting page.

[image]

Comment: This only shows the amount of days left.

Comment: @Senseful - its not possible to know how many "minutes" are left.

Comment: so you mean it happens at some random time on that day and that each month it's at a different time?

Comment: @Senseful - ofcourse not but there is no way to know via their web interface and i have check their API and they have no method for that either. Atleast their data model don't expose it to outsiders. http://www.evernote.com/about/developer/api/evernote-api.htm#_Toc277181445